# Spring Boot: "Cycling" in the request answer, when entities have bidirectional references (ManyToMany, FetchType.LAZY)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, bidirectional-relation

Good day,

I am studing the Spring Boot. Here is my prodject - https://github.com/Alex1182-St/java-spring-jpa-postgresql.git

I have 2 entities in it:

AppUserEntity - https://github.com/Alex1182-St/java-spring-jpa-postgresql/blob/master/src/main/java/com/java/javaspringjpapostgresql/entities/AppUserEntity.java

and RoleEntity - https://github.com/Alex1182-St/java-spring-jpa-postgresql/blob/master/src/main/java/com/java/javaspringjpapostgresql/entities/RoleEntity.java

The entities have bi-directional references (ManyToMany, FetchType.LAZY).

**My problem is that when my method (method appUserById2WithPost in the AppUserController)  returns an entity and not the DTO, then I receive a "cycling" in the answer.**
Here is how this cyckling looks like -

```
    "id": "e68e915f-e684-4b95-820a-a670a7bea677",
    "appUserLogin": "Login9",
    "appUserPassword": "$2a$10$ENyk.YDPLn4zsq1JL6Nol.97kwIlZVAK7pCei8I9i6LhzMj52UAN.",
    "roles": [
        {
            "id": "7a8abe8d-ab02-4e00-a463-a7d23df05778",
            "name": "USER",
            "appUsers": [
                {
                    "id": "e68e915f-e684-4b95-820a-a670a7bea677",
                    "appUserLogin": "Login9",
                    "appUserPassword": "$2a$10$ENyk.YDPLn4zsq1JL6Nol.97kwIlZVAK7pCei8I9i6LhzMj52UAN.",
                    "roles": [
                        {
                            "id": "7a8abe8d-ab02-4e00-a463-a7d23df05778",
                            "name": "USER",
                            "appUsers": [
                                {
                                    "id": "e68e915f-e684-4b95-820a-a670a7bea677",
                                    "appUserLogin": "Login9",
                                    "appUserPassword": "$2a$10$ENyk.YDPLn4zsq1JL6Nol.97kwIlZVAK7pCei8I9i6LhzMj52UAN.",
                                    "roles": [
                                        {
                                            "id": "7a8abe8d-ab02-4e00-a463-a7d23df05778",
                                            "name": "USER",
                                            "appUsers": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "e68e915f-e684-4b95-820a-a670a7bea677",
                                                    "appUserLogin": "Login9",
                                                    "appUserPassword": "$2a$10$ENyk.YDPLn4zsq1JL6Nol.97kwIlZVAK7pCei8I9i6LhzMj52UAN.",
                                                    "roles": [
                                                        { AND SO ON...
```

In the Idea's console I have such mistake - **Failure while trying to resolve exception [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException]**

Controller with the method - https://github.com/Alex1182-St/java-spring-jpa-postgresql/blob/master/src/main/java/com/java/javaspringjpapostgresql/controllers/AppUserController.java

Of course I can solve it by returning a DTO (like in the method appUserByIdWithPost) or by using annotations @JsonIdentityInfo in the Entities.

But I am afraid that a mistake will stiil be in the project. I want to solve it. But I cannot find what is the cause of it. Can someone help me?
Or maybe such behaviour is normal?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: You are creating circular dependency between AppUserEntity and Role. I you are not bounded by business requirements to have  it specifically like this, break this cycle.  So in case you will read  Roles , remove Set of AppUserEntitties.  If you need it that , way , than in controller ,where you are about to unwrap all objects  for marshaling , you need to manually assemble the response , to break intention of marshaler  going from AppUserEntity to Role and back.

Comment: this behavior is normal. the only thing, i think you should change toString methods. you can override toString and remove part about "appUsers" . Except that, you should return DTO in ideal case. there is nothing wrong with your code. Just change the toStrings.

Comment: Do you mean changing (transforming) the answer of request from entity to DTO when you are telling about marshalling and/or toString?

Answer (score 0):

I would say this behavior is normal for bidirectional relationships and handling it with JSON annotations is fine (although not necessary with the @JsonIdentityInfo: you can consider [JsonIgnore](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) or [JsonValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html)).

Another question is if you need the bidirectional relationship (is many-to-many on the RoleEntity really necessary?) or even if the RoleEntity should be an entity at all.

Comment: I need a RoleEntity in purpose of security. And becouse I am studing I have used the biderectional many to many relation. Just to see how it is work. If it is normal behaviour, than I just change to unidirectional relations or will use JSON annotations